# Boot Problems sh: can't access tty: job control turned off

Tags: raspbian, gpio, boot, boot-issues

I had one of the rf24 transceivers connected directly to the pi using jumper cables and everything worked fine. then I bought a case and was forced to use a ribbon cable. With out the transceiver connected, it booted fine, with it connected, the above boot error was given. I checked the wiring and it appeared to be ok. But it wouldn't boot. What could be causing this? I was thinking to add `"avoid_safe_mode=1"` to `config.txt` but A) I want to be absolutely sure there is no damage to the pi by doing so. and B) I can't find the `config.txt` file.

wired up as per: [image: wiring diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is usually safe to add `avoid_safe_mode=1` to `config.txt`. An exception might be if you are overclocking but other than that, just go ahead and try. You can read more about it here
http://elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode
The `config.txt` file is in `/boot`